# ¿Cómo mostrar enlace si existe una palabra especifica registrada en la base de datos - PHP?

Tags: php

Mediante un `is_null` puedo mostrar un contenido diferente si existe registro o no en una columna especifica, sin la necesidad de realizar otra consulta.

Si en la columna `description` no existe registro *NULL* no se muestra el contenido que tiene el `echo` a imprimir pero si existe contenido se mostrara.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if(!is_null($row['description'])){
  echo '<span class="toggle"></span>
  <ul class="inner"><div class="aaaaaaa">
    <li>'.$row['description'].'</li></div>
  </ul>';
}
```

De la misma forma o algo similar sin la necesidad de realizar otra consulta o una nueva consulta, como puedo mostrar un enlace solo si en la columna `vista_previa` existe la palabra `yes` y si existe la palabra `not` no mostrar el enlace.

```
id  |  vista_previa  |  description  |  url
1          yes             one         one.php
2          not             two         two.php
```

---

```
<a href="'.$row['url'].'"></>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡El código ya lo tienes! 
Te sugerio que en tu consulta a la BD *(no indicas cual es)* agregues según corresponda para que en lugar de NULL te devuelva un valor *(por ejemplo cadena vacia)* en MySQL sería (usando [IsNull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) con [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT Id, IF(IsNULL(vista_previa), "", vista_previa) vista_previa 
       [, otroCampo[, otroCampo,....]] 
FROM LaTablaOrigen
```

con lo anterior en vez de

```
if(!is_null($row['description']))
```

seria

```
if($row['description']!="")
```

por consiguiente para el caso que pides sería

```
if($row['vista_previa']=="yes"){
  /* Lo que quieras hacer */
  echo '<a href="'.$row['url'].'"></>';
}
```

> Editado

entonces usa el operador ternario (u operador condicional) `?`:

```
if((is_null($row['vista_previa'])?"":$row['vista_previa'])=="yes"){
  /* Lo que quieras hacer */
  echo '<a href="'.$row['url'].'"></>';
}
```

Comment: Hola :) no mostré la consulta porque por medio de `if(!is_null($row['description'])){}` puedo mostrar un dato diferente sin necesidad de modificar la consulta. La idea es encontrar algo similar sin hacer cambios en la consulta, y sin crear una nueva consulta.

Comment: Que función cumple el nuevo código, lo he solucionado con sus primeras opciones, solo comente porque no añadí la consulta a mi pregunta, estaba probando pero como mencione lo solucione con una de sus opciones `if($row['vista_previa']=="yes"){//muestro la url}else{//otro dato en caso de no existir la palabra yes}` **Pero me quedo la duda, que función cumple el nuevo código añadido**

Comment: Si te refieres al operador ternario, es por si en algun momento (futuro) el dato pudiera ser NULL ya quede solventada esa posibilidad y se evalue más adecuadamente; y claro también para ilustrarte dejandote una opción adicional como evaluar cualquier otro dato NULL y en esa mismo línea evaluar si corresponde a un valor esperado sin más.